# Alert user if item already exists within a HashSet

Tags: java, android, alert

My code uses a HashSet in order to not duplicate entries saved to the set. I want to implement an alert for user who enter the same data or string that is already stored. Is this something that can be done? I have taken Java for 2 days now and I will be grateful for any advise.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout); 

    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    text2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            list.add("Books");
            list.add("Newspapers");
            list.add("Magazines");
            String listString = "";

            for (String s : list) {
                listString += s + " - ";
            }
            text2.setText(listString);
            }
        });

    sButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    eText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    sButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             Log.v("EditText", eText.getText().toString());
             list.add(eText.getText().toString());  
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at AlertDialog in the Android documentation.  Also, there are plenty of good examples on StackOverflow for using AlertDialogs.

Comment: I do not see a `HashSet` in your code.

Comment: you can check if list.contains(eText.getText().toString()) in your onClick event of sButton. if list.contains return false, you can then add new item into the list.

Comment: The hash set is defined as global just above the code i pasted on here. It is defined as such:
    HashSet<String> list = new HashSet<String>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HashSet's `add ()` method returns `false` if the element was not actually added, i.e. it was already in there. Assuming `list` is your HashSet, you could write:

```
if (!list.add(eText.getText().toString())) {
    // display alert
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Jan Van den bosch

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the HashSet if it's contain the value before adding it. Then you can show the message if it's already present, or add it if not.

sample code:

```
HashSet val;
// ....
if(val.contains(newValue)){
   //show alert;
} else {
   val.add(newValue);
}
```

The reality is that you lose some part of why you want to use a hashSet in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing your `HashSet` called 'list' is defined somewhere else in the code.

Regardless, the `add` method on the `HashSet` class returns a boolean. It will return `true` if it can add the new item to the set, `false` if it is already in the set.

So you just need to use something like;

```
if( list.add(eText.getText().toString()) ) {
  //it has been added to the list
} else {
  // show an alert
}
```

See the Java docs for more... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: Yes!. You are correct. The hash set is define above as global. I will try this and come back. Thanks for your help.